If the inverting and non inverting terminal of an op-amp are at the same voltage then how does a differential amplifier work?
I'm just starting off studying op-amps, I had a question, if V+ and V- are approximately equal, then Vd is approx. 0. Then, in a differential amplifier, if I give the inputs as, say, 5V and 2V, I should be getting 3V*gain at the output. But if the input terminals are at the same voltage, then Vd will be almost 0 and with a gain of, say 3, the output will also be 0? I don't quite get that.. Please do try to answer intuitively.

Image source: Electronics Tutorials - The Differential Amplifier

Keshav, R3 is negative feedback. It allows the output to alter what is seen at Va. The opamp, having a very high "multiplier" times Vd (as you write it), very quickly alters its output so that the altered voltage at Va can be made equal to Vb (close to it.) You can just apply KCL to this circuit. Or use the usual closed loop gain equation given the open loop gain and a negative feedback factor between 0 and 1.

When you talk of gain of 3, what gain is it? Overall closed loop gain or open loop gain of the opamp? What is Vd? Is it V1-V2 or Va-Vb? For your example, is V1=5V & V2=3V? Please update the question with these clarifications.


if V+ and V- are approximately equal, then Vd is approx. 0.

This answer assumes you meant to say Vout and not Vd so...
Not quite true. If they are approximately zero then the output (Vout) is approximately zero multiplied by the open loop gain. And, of course, the open loop gain might be a million so, if V+ and V- are 10 μV apart then the output might be +/- 10 volts.

But if the input terminals are at the same voltage, then Vd will be
almost 0 and with a gain of, say 3, the output will also be 0?

Again I'm assuming you mean Vout and not Vd (which you haven't disclosed in your question) so...
If the input voltages are exactly the same voltage then Vout (in an ideal op-amp) has to be zero volts but, that's missing the point of how op-amps work.
Real op-amps try to make the inverting input the same level as the non-inverting input but, this is still an approximation because real op-amps don't have infinite open-loop gain.
We all have to live with the error and accept it as what real op-amps can deliver. It's not ideal but, in most cases it's waaaaay more than what we need in real life.

Hey Andy, by Vd, i meant the voltage difference, V2-V1

OK but the main body of my answer remains the same @KeshavNair

So basically, an opamp takes the difference of the 2 inputs and amplifies it, but it saturates since the gain is very high.
In a differential amplifier it is able to control the gain using feedback and resistors, hence we can design it for unity gain and get V2-V1.
Is my thought process right?

The output should not saturate. Av >> 1 means that, if there is negative feedback, the input voltages will be equal; V+ = V- ( or in your example, Va = Vb).

@KeshavNair if you don't have negative feedback it will likely saturate (or act as a comparator).

You are confusing the heart of the circuit, the op-amp itself, with the surrounding components connected in a way that makes the whole circuit act as a differential amplifier.
The op-amp drives the output to any voltage to keep it's inverting and non-inverting terminals at identical voltage regardless of to which kind of circuit it is connected to - assuming negative feedback within operating limits of the amplifier.
The whole circuit can be written as an equation using KCL and KVL how it works as a differential amplifer.

The terminals will be at the same voltage if the op-amp has infinite gain. With real op-amps, there will be a voltage difference if the output is anything other than zero.
How big will it be? We have this equation:
$$V_{out} = A_{0} \times (V_{in+}-V_{in-})$$
So for \$A_{0}\$ less than infinity and \$V_{out}\$ greater than zero, there must be some voltage difference. An op-amp with a gain \$A_{0}\$ of 10,000 and \$V_{out}\$ of 1V will have a voltage difference of 1/10,000V or 0.1mV.
More here: Why is op-amp output not zero if inputs have the same voltage?

I get that an op-amp has infinite gain and as such, any difference in the voltage between its terminals will be amplified to +-Vsat.
So in a differential amplifier the gain is controlled using negative feedback and hence the output can be controlled to a gain like unity gain to give V2-V1.
Is my intuition right?

Basically, yes. I encourage you to follow the link, there is an MIT courseware deck that goes over the theory of both real and ideal op-amps.

We can assume the op-amp is ideal. That equation is not useful as a starting point for analyzing how differential amps work. In ideal op-amp, A0 is infinite, Va equals Vb so their difference is zero, and yet, output can still be calculated from inputs and resistors so no need to deal with equations that multiply zero with infinity which I guess should be zero.

Thank you, will check it out @hacktastical

Also the same approach how to calculate is behind the link to the original tutorial with the picture.
